# Express error handling in promises

Tags: node.js, express, error-handling, promise

I am having an issue with errors in express, and promisses.

I am trying to have the best way to handle errors, create a standard way to do it in my app.

However, I am in front of an issue :

```
validate(req.body)
.catch(e => next(new APIError(400, e)))
.then(validatedbody => searchdatabase(validatedbody))
.then(dbResult => validate(dbResult))
.catch(e => next(new APIError(500, e)))
// results from db should always be valid
.then(validatedDbResult => res.json(validatedDbResult))
```

If the body is wrong, we should stop and send the error, and the error will be sent using the error handling middleware, however dut to how promises work, it will also continue to the next step (searching in the DB).

What should I do ?
And am I correctly handling errors in a first place ?

Thank you very much,
Giltho

Comment: Named parameters in `APIError`? I don't think that'll work.

Comment: Yes indeed, correcting it, that was an example, it is not my actual code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just re-throw the error, and only *handle* it at the very end of the chain:

```
validate(req.body)
.catch(e => { throw new APIError(400, e); })
.then(validatedbody =>
  searchdatabase(validatedbody)
  .then(validate)
  .catch(e => { throw new APIError(500, e); })
)
.then(validatedDbResult => res.json(validatedDbResult),
      next)
```

Comment: If I rethrow the error, it status will change on the second throw using your code, won't it ?

Comment: @Giltho No, that's why I nested the second `catch` to only catch rejections from `searchdatabase` and `validate` :-)

Comment: oh it's nested didn't see that, well i guess that would work thanks !!